# Java.lang.reflect.invocationTargetException in hibernate

Tags: eclipse

Any one please solve my problem. I'm getting java.lang.reflect.invocationTargetException while I'm trying to save an object into oracle database(Oracle 10G).

Here is my model class named Student.java

```
package org.hibernatetest;

public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Here is my mapping file named Student.hbm.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.hibernatetest.Student" table="STUDENT_2018">
        <id name="id" column="STUDENT_ID"/>
        <property name="name" column="STUDENT_NAME"></property>
        <property name="email" column="STUDENT_EMAIL"></property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

here is configuration file named as hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username">Test</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Test</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</property>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
            <property name="show_sql">true</property>
            <mapping resource="resource/Student.hbm.xml"/>
        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

here is my persistent class named Test.java

```
package org.hibernatetest;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student st = new Student();
        st.setId(1);
        st.setName("Mohan");
        st.setEmail("mmohan668@gmail.com");

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        SessionFactory sf = cfg.configure("resource/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        Session s = sf.openSession();
        s.save(st);
        s.beginTransaction().commit();          
        s.evict(st);
    }

}
```

Please help to resolve my problem . Thanks in advance.

Comment: `InvocationTargetException` is a very broad description. Please add full stacktrace to your post